# API integration (Eventbrite)

Tags: apex, rest-api, api

I want to do like that from my custom visual force page use can search event under my organization only not in whole eventbrite data.
End point i am using is as below.

But still its getting me an error, how can i write endpoint code which search event under my organization id?

```
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?location.address=' + pagequery);
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?organizer.id='9035174576);

    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ***********');
    req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    System.debug(req.getendpoint());
    HttpResponse res;
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '9035174576' at line 35 column 76

Answer (score 2):

Your endpoint string is malformed:

```
req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?organizer.id='9035174576);
```

should be:

```
req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?organizer.id=9035174576');
```

Not sure why you're setting the endpoint twice though.

Comment: can i set multiple endpoint in one line? if yes can you please tell me how.

Comment: You should only be setting it once, to a single URL. If you need to set requests to two URLs they will be two separate HTTP requests.

Comment: You should only be able to add one Endpoint at a time if you want multiple callouts then you have to make multiple requests